# animate() not working in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have a script that when button is hovered will animate it so it pops up, unfortunately i can't get it working in IE at all. It's using jQuery and works in all other browsers.

Please see the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JHS5g/1/ I've tried to mimic my actual code as much as possible and have therefore left in some of the surrounding code.

```
$("#main-nav div").hover(function() {
  $(this).stop().animate({
    top: "-40px"
  }, { queue: false, duration: 200 });
}, function() {
  $(this).stop().animate({
    top: "0px"
  }, { queue: false, duration: 200 });
});
```

I actually think it's a html or css error thats causing it to break because when i test the jquery code on it's own it works but i just can't pinpoint it.

I've noticed the fiddle is some of the html markup in red, indicating an error? but again i just can't see it.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it to work by adding `display: inline-block` to the div you are animating

I've updated your [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JHS5g/13/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the jQuery. [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JHS5g/14/)

What you are attempting to do is extraordinarily simple in CSS using a basic `:hover` psuedoclass and `transition` CSS property.

The best part? It'll even work in older versions of IE (down to IE7 - before that `:hover` won't work on elements that aren't `<a>`), although it will not animate in IE8 or below.

That's okay though, because transitions are eye-candy, NOT functionality, and therefore not required. Plus it provides a little bonus for people who are smart enough to not disable Windows Update.

Comment: I completely agree, however it was pretty much the only requirement given to me from the client that the navigation buttons 'pop up just like my old site' and when i asked the client to test the functionality in Google Chrome (to guarantee 100% compatibility for the benefit of the demo) i received the reply "i don't know what you are talking about" so I have no choice but to make sure it will work back to IE 8 (screw IE 7!) and jquery is the safer bet here.